# HTML text not formatting

Tags: c#, .net, sql, html

so I have HTML formatted Sql text stored in my database, I populate the contents of a `<p></p>` tag with it on page load, but though HTML tags are showing up in the text they are not formatting the text. Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: a sample of the HTML would be helpful

Comment: Look at the source view of the generated HTML. Chances are your app is encoding the HTML tags int &lt; and &rt;

Answer (score 1):

So how you outputting the HTML?
You have a HtmlGenericControl running at server representing the <p> tag? Maybe you using InnerText instead of InnerHtml?
Or, it could be a HTML encoding/decoding issue. Take a look at the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Use "html_entity_decode($str)" on the stored text when displaying.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are "populating the contents of a `<p></p>` tag" - what exactly do you mean?  Typically, the choices that I see are A) using a Label and assigning the Text field or B) simply entering a string value directly where you want your HTML to appear.

```
<%#StringToWriteToHTMLStream%>
```

You'll need to call Databind() after setting the string contents from your database record.

Is this all you are after?